# Users unable to access Facebook app, "An Error has occurred with ____ app" message

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-oauth

Four days ago, I finished work on an iframed Facebok app and flipped the switch to take it live - ie. I added the url of the canvas page to my app's settings page. Everything had been going smoothly in testing, and for our testers group, things continued to go smoothly. No errors were happening within that group.

We started sending around the app page link to a close group of friends, and many - but not all of them reported that they were getting a "Error occurred with . Please try again later." message. When we send those same users to the actual canvas url - ie. outside of the Facebook iframe - they're able to access the app without issue. What's more annoying - if they then go back and try the app page link again, everything works fine.

Further, the app does not appear in search results until *after* the user has successfully authenticated the first time. I know apps that are used by a person are weighted to the top, but the thing is, the app doesn't appear *at all* in the list until they've authenticated the first time.

Some ideas we've kicked around at work re: the cause - First, since the SSL transition was made rather recently, perhaps there are some kinks in the system still. (Our app is 100% SSL.) Second, that there's something up with the authenticated referrals stuff, as that *might* explain why folks are having problems inside Facebook but not outside.

It almost seems as if the app is in sandbox mode - but it clearly isn't, and hasn't been for weeks; we've had a mobile web app - that does not exhibit these behaviors - live since late December.

Has anyone run into similar problems? Are there specific things I should check in either settings or in my init code? For reference, here's the canvas url:

https://likes.willowtreeapps.com/d/

and here's the app url:

http://apps.facebook.com/214113781988679/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I tested your both urls and none of them seems to work:
for the first one:
An error occurred with Likes! Please try again later.

and loop in the same page for the second one.
But if I stop the page and click that like button I got authorization pop up.

Probably you are experiencing about parsing `signed_request` and maybe if you are redirecting first users to authentication page about redirecting and getting back him and again `signed_request`

You may check also your javascript codes or server side codes for redirection from myapp.com to apps.facebook.com/myapp

Finally have very detailed logging system as you are starting up a facebook app, and even check exceptions hits logs

good luck

Edit:

Here are more work for the first case:

This is url in address bar
https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=214113781988679&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/214113781988679/&response_type=none&display=page&perms=offline_access,user_likes,friends_likes&auth_referral=1

whose parts are:

https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=214113781988679
method=permissions.request
**redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/214113781988679/**
response_type=none
display=page
perms=offline_access,user_likes,friends_likes
auth_referral=1

and redirect_uri should be like **https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/**
but I am not sure it is the case for connect